# How to click on radio input inside a form with selenium and python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to select the first input with `id="c8829_pk_1050211"` with selenium and Python but I cannot do it.

```
<div class="form-group "><label id="d8829_lk_10502" class="control-label col-sm-12" style="text-align: left;" for="c8829_pk_10502">¿Asiste regularmente a clases? <b>*</b></label><div class="controls col-sm-12"><div class="container-fluid"><div class="row"><div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input id="c8829_pk_1050211" name="c8829_pk_10502" value="11" class="  ef_radio inline" type="radio" required="">
                    100%
                </label>
            </div>
        <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input id="c8829_pk_1050210" name="c8829_pk_10502" value="10" class="  ef_radio inline" type="radio" required="">
                    90%
                </label>
            </div>
        <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input id="c8829_pk_105029" name="c8829_pk_10502" value="9" class="  ef_radio inline" type="radio" required="">
                    80%
                </label>
            </div>
        <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input id="c8829_pk_105028" name="c8829_pk_10502" value="8" class="  ef_radio inline" type="radio" required="">
                    70%
                </label>
            </div>
        <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input id="c8829_pk_105027" name="c8829_pk_10502" value="7" class="  ef_radio inline" type="radio" required="">
                    60%
                </label>
            </div>
        <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input id="c8829_pk_105026" name="c8829_pk_10502" value="6" class="  ef_radio inline" type="radio" required="">
                    50%
                </label>
            </div>
        <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input id="c8829_pk_105025" name="c8829_pk_10502" value="5" class="  ef_radio inline" type="radio" required="">
                    40%
                </label>
            </div>
        <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input id="c8829_pk_105024" name="c8829_pk_10502" value="4" class="  ef_radio inline" type="radio" required="">
                    30%
                </label>
            </div>
        <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input id="c8829_pk_105023" name="c8829_pk_10502" value="3" class="  ef_radio inline" type="radio" required="">
                    20%
                </label>
            </div>
        <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input id="c8829_pk_105022" name="c8829_pk_10502" value="2" class="  ef_radio inline" type="radio" required="">
                    10%
                </label>
            </div>
        <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input id="c8829_pk_105021" name="c8829_pk_10502" value="1" class="  ef_radio inline" type="radio" required="">
                    No opina
                </label>
            </div>
        </div></div><span class="js-error"></span></div></div>
```

What I did was

```
button = driver.find_element_by_id('d8829_lk_10502')
button.click()
```

I have a `time.sleep(20)` prior to the `button = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'c8829_pk_1050211') button.click()` to wait for the entire form to load

I don't know for what reason it is not selected. because with the other drivers.find_element_by_id it does. The id , name and class are: `id="formulario"`, `name="formulario"` and `class="form-horizontal"`.

In the visual studio code terminal, it shows me the following message when it reaches the line to click on the radio button

```
  button = driver.find_element_by_id('d8829_lk_10502')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/salva/PycharmProjects/encuestasDocentes/main.py", line 40, in <module>
    button = driver.find_element_by_id('d8829_lk_10502')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 472, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1244, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="d8829_lk_10502"]"}
```

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a delay in loading the site? Sometimes, you have to wait for the element to show up.

Comment: Are you getting some errors, if yes, please add the error Traceback. Please always provide a minimum reproducible work/code snippets in order to reproduce the error and thus provide you some way around to solve it. 

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have modified the question. I have added the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code:

```
button = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'c8829_pk_1050211')
button.click()
```

Don't forget to import 'By' like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: It hasn't worked either. I have a time.sleep(20) prior to the button = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'c8829_pk_1050211')
button.click() to wait for the entire form to load

Comment: So you can tried the function WebDriverWait from selenium
Are you launching the browser in headless mode ?